# Updating a file in a zip archive from STDIN

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, shell, pipe, compression

I want to update/freshen a file in a zip archive with the contents of `stdin`. So far I haven't been able to find a way to tell the `zip` command that the contents of `stdin` correspond to a particular file.

E.g. (the last line is how I'd expect it to work but it doesn't make any changes to the zip file):

```
~/D/tmp ♪ unzip -l sample.odt # an odt file is actually a zip file
Archive:  sample.odt
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
       39  01-06-10 00:46   mimetype
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/statusbar/
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/floater/
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/popupmenu/
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/progressbar/
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/menubar/
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/toolbar/
        0  01-06-10 00:46   Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/
     3374  01-06-10 00:46   content.xml
    11837  01-06-10 00:46   styles.xml
      957  01-06-10 00:46   meta.xml
     1060  01-06-10 00:46   Thumbnails/thumbnail.png
     8086  01-06-10 00:46   settings.xml
     1889  01-06-10 00:46   META-INF/manifest.xml
 --------                   -------
    27242                   15 files
~/D/tmp ♪ unzip -p sample.odt meta.xml > tmp.xml
~/D/tmp ♪ # modify tmp.xml somehow
~/D/tmp ♪ cat tmp.xml | zip sample.odt -u meta.xml
```

EDIT (Taken from my comment below):
I can't just load the file directly into the zip file by referencing the new version because the initial extraction is never being redirected to a file in my actual situation. Instead to a database where it undergoes some text processing in a background queue. It is then substituted back into the document on demand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just do:

```
unzip -p sample.odt meta.xml
#modify meta.xml
zip sample.odt -u meta.xml
rm meta.xml
```

Then you don't have to worry about doing wierd gyrations to pipeline everything back in

In response to you comment, the only two suggestions I can think of is

a) Write the file out to a random temp directory `/tmp/<random_number>/meta.xml` then do a `zip sample.odt -u /tmp/<random_number>/meta.xml`

b) Ask on Stack overflow if there is a programatic way to manipulate your zip file.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that. The initial extraction is never being redirected to an actual file, but instead to a database where it undergoes some text processing in a background queue. It is then substituted back into the document on demand.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip` man page describes how a single dash can be used to represent STDIN or STDOUT in a command-line, so `zip` can be used in a pipeline.

Look for **Streaming input and output** in the man page.

BUT since you're using STDIN and **not** specifying a file name with this method, it's not going to work as you'd like with muti-file zip archives.

As the mention of `gunzip` in the man page suggests, it's meant for archives containing single files.

In the same way `gzip filename` produces filename.gz, `zip` can produce filename.zip **except that zip requires you to explicitly name the zip file**.

[HERE'S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019603/how-do-you-specify-filenames-within-a-zip-when-creating-it-on-the-command-line-fr) a relevant new post on SO. I nearly fell off my chair when I saw this.

Comment: I tried adding a '-' but it just added a file to the archive of name '-' (with the correct contents though). Specifying the file name to replace directly fails with an error, because it can't find the file on the system

Comment: It sounds to me that `zip` becomes a kind of replacement for `gzip` when STDIN is the source of data. I saw nothing in the man page which would allow you to say "By the way, the data from STDIN is really a file called xxxx", so it has no name and is really only suitable for archives containing a single (anonymous) file.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'll do it programmatically, which might actually end up being faster anyway.